# Dynamically update header in ionic angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ionic-framework

I have been stumped on this problem for a while now . when i navigate between different child page the ion-content is well updated but the header content is not showing anything until I reload the page (using web browser), I think it doesn't make sense since I would like to make a mobile app. I'm loading the content dynamically (via HTTP GET)

In one of my views, I have the following

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
         <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-right"></button>
      <ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
         <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
      <ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-nav-title> 
         <h1>{{header.title}}</h1>
      </ion-nav-title>
            <ion-content>
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="item in list">
                    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectcategories(item.id)" 
                    ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item.id) > -1"></label>
                    {{ item.catname |uppercase}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

in the controller for the above view, I have

```
app.controller('usercategoryController',
    function($scope,getcategories,$log)
        {
            $log.info("userCategoryController Called ...");
            $scope.list=getcategories;
            $scope.header={};
            $scope.header.title="Categories";
    });
```

my app config is :

```
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
            function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider)
            {
                 $stateProvider

                state('user',{
                     abstract:true,
                     url:"/user",
                     templateUrl:'views/user.html',
                 }).state('user.categories',{
                     url:"/categories",
                     templateUrl:'views/categories.html',
                     controller: 'usercategoryController',
                     resolve:{
                         getcategories: function(userService) {
                             return userService.getcategories();
                        }
                     }, 

                 })
                 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/user');
            }
 ]);
```

and here is my abstract view

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```

it always shows a blue header with no content inside till i reload the browser. for the header title I have tried both title and view-title attribute with no success .

if someone has a solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using and you want to show a button in the header bar only when an input/textarea is filled (not empty), then you can do the following.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-light">
  <h1 class="title">{{$root.Title}}</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button button-clear icon ion-checkmark-round" ng-click="" ng-if="$root.Title"></button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

and inside "ion-content" -

```
<div class="row>
  <textarea placeholder="" rows="3" maxlength="100" ng-model="$root.Title" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
</div>
```

Otherwise just using ng-if="Title" in the header bar will not work. Not sure if this is applicable in your case, but I hope it can help in some small way at least. Cheers.