# AngularJS data displayed only after reload

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My data comes from a [JSON](http://www.sortiraujourdhui.fr/api/?u=Jacques%20Seite&k=d3bfbf2d30254ac827f1ea07d38aa3de&data=categorie&cat=33) (link to be seen)

I can see in my logs that data are loaded

I can't display value in my template (need to reload browser to be displayed)

As can be seen bottom my template is very simple `selectedCategories.name` in the title and `events` values

First is displayed after reloaded page, second never.

Thanks for your help

**Factory :**

```
.factory('selectedCategoriesService', function($http, $stateParams) {
        var selectedCategories = [];

        return {
        getselectedCategories: function(){
            return $http.get('http://www.myapi.com&data=categorie', { params: { cat: $stateParams.id } }).then(function(response){
                selectedCategories = response.data;
                delete selectedCategories.api;
                return response.data;
            });
        },
        getselectedCategorie: function(selectedCategorieId){
            for(i=0;i<selectedCategories.length;i++){
                if(selectedCategories[i].id == selectedCategorieId){
                    return selectedCategories[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Controller :**

```
.controller('CategoriesListDetailCtrl',function($scope, $stateParams, selectedCategoriesService, $ionicModal){
  selectedCategoriesService.getselectedCategories().then(function(selectedCategories){
    $scope.selectedCategories = selectedCategories[0];
    console.log("Categorie = " + JSON.stringify(selectedCategories[0]));
    })
})
```

**Template :**

```
<ion-pane>

  <ion-view view-title="{{selectedCategories.name}}">

    <ion-content class="has-header">

        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" collection-repeat="event in events | DateDivider" divider-collection-repeat>

           <h2>{{event.title}}</h2>

        </ion-item>

    </ion-content>

  </ion-view>

</ion-pane>
```

Comment: where's  `$scope.events` defined?

Comment: `$scope.events` is an array in my JSON http://www.sortiraujourdhui.fr/api/?u=Jacques%20Seite&k=d3bfbf2d30254ac827f1ea07d38aa3de&data=categorie&cat=33

Answer (score 0):

This could be a digest cycle issue, You may need to use `$scope.$apply()`

```
.controller('CategoriesListDetailCtrl',function($scope, $stateParams, selectedCategoriesService, $ionicModal){
  selectedCategoriesService.getselectedCategories().then(function(selectedCategories){
    $scope.selectedCategories = selectedCategories[0];
    $scope.$apply()
    console.log("Categorie = " + JSON.stringify(selectedCategories[0]));
    })
})
```

Comment: I try `if(!$scope.$$phase) {$scope.$apply();}` but nothing append

Answer (score 0):

If the title doesn't display it's because in my template i use :

```
<ion-view title="{{content.title}}">
    ....
```

in spite of :

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>{{content.title}}</ion-nav-title>
    ...
```

Thanks to [@Dunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257786/angularjs-using-ionic-framework-data-binding-on-header-title-not-working?rq=1)